# Remove log4net system properties from output

Tags: c#, log4net

I want to use LogicalThreadContext to pass some context information in my WCF service. I need to pass different properties. In C# I has code

```
LogicalThreadContext.Properties["MyProperty"] = 1;
```

In log4net config I have

```
<log4net>
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppenderSize" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="Logs\Log.log" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="3" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d [%2t] [%property] %level %m%n"  />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppenderSize" />
</root>
</log4net>
```

And in log I got

```
2015-11-03 16:24:36,313 [10] [{MyProperty=1, log4net:Identity=, log4net:UserName=User, log4net:HostName=User}] INFO  - Info
```

I don't want to have system properties log4net:Identity, log4net:UserName and log4net:HostName in log. How to do this? I can write config like this

```
conversionPattern value="%d [%2t] [%property{MyProperty}] %level %m%n"
```

But I have several properties in code and I want to see only properties that I added. Code

```
LogicalThreadContext.Properties.Remove("log4net:UserName");
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show your full configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that it's posible to remove only log4net:HostName property with code
`GlobalContext.Properties.Remove(LoggingEvent.HostNameProperty)`.
log4net:Identity and log4net:UserName cannot be removed because of  `CreateCompositeProperties` method in `log4net.Core.LoggingEvent` class https://github.com/apache/log4net/blob/trunk/src/Core/LoggingEvent.cs. 
It adds these properties without any conditions and so it's imposible to remove them for the last log4net version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

```
GlobalContext.Properties.Clear();
```

Worked for me.